# Access VBA me.filter

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I'm struggling to filter using 2 keywords.

I want to be able to filter Keyword1 AND Keyword2 on a single column in Access

```
ElseIf Not IsNull([Keyword1_Filter]) And Not IsNull([Keyword2_Filter]) Then

Me.Filter = "Description_Of_Query Like '*" & Keyword1_Filter & "*'" OR & 
Keyword2_Filter & "*'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are a bit weird. The filter needs to be a valid SQL where clause.

Use the following:

```
Me.Filter = "Description_Of_Query Like '*" & Keyword1_Filter & "*' OR Description_Of_Query Like '*" & Keyword2_Filter & "*'"
```

Of course, if both statements need to be true, use `AND` and not `OR`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Also take special care if your keywords can possibly include the single quote character.